# Clarification wrt proof for linear regression cost function being convex

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-semidefinite

I have trouble understanding the proof which computes hessian of J to see if the optimisation problem is convex.
[why is the least square cost function for linear regression convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2774106/why-is-the-least-square-cost-function-for-linear-regression-convex)

The proof claims that the matrix $^T $ is positive semidefinite.
It's obvious that the product is symmetric. But I am not able to see why it is positive semidefinite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can gather the definition of positive semi-definiteness from

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definiteness_of_a_matrix

We have to prove that:

$v^T X^T X v$ $\ge 0$

Notice that, the above expression can be rewritten as:

$v^T X^T X v$ = $(Xv)^T. Xv$ = $|| X.v ||_2 $ (Which is the euclidean norm of $X.v$)

Since, the euclidean norm of the vector is a sum of squares the result follows.